# Is there a way to Invite a user to manage Youtube using an API?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client, youtube-api

There is a way to manually do it (https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/4524878?hl=en).

But i want to do it with the help of an api call .

For example :

In google analytics we use the below command to insert user using the google analytics api call for management.

```
files = analytics.management().accountUserLinks().insert(
              accountId = account_id,
              body={
                'permissions': {
                  'effective' : ['READ_AND_ANALYZE'],
                  'local': ['EDIT','MANAGE_USERS']
                },
                'userRef': {'email': 'xyz@gmail.com'}
                }).execute()
```

Comment: how far have you tried?

Comment: I have looked at all the different Youtube API's and none of them seem to have the resource for inviting other users. @InfinityTM

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python do you find anything here?

Comment: No. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs as you can see in this doc there is no reference to any api call for the mentioned problem.

Comment: then you can't i guess

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Did you check the API documentation?

Comment: Yes i checked the API doc, nothing there !